# Cache many images with picasso

Tags: android, picasso

How to cache many images let's say 10 with Picasso before doing any further (that means that I need to run code after caching all images)?

Comment: See related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978828/using-disk-caching-in-picasso-android-lib.

Comment: I have read that thread and I can't figure out.. I only want to cache a collection of images from network and after all images are cached let the app flow go further..