# I don't get any errors downloading, viewing, and saving an image, but I get OutOfMemoryError when reading that image from its file

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I am downloading images from the internet which I am displaying in my app. I am saving those images to file so that I can read them from disk instead of accessing the internet again.

On modern devices I am not getting any issues with this approach, but on an older device (which I am intending to target) I am getting an OutOfMemoryError when loading images **from file**.

The baffling thing is **I do not have any issue if the image is downloaded from the internet, just when the bitmap is read in from file.** It's like the image is getting much larger when I save it to file or something, but I don't know why.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget(Heap Size=9607KB, Allocated=5143KB, Bitmap Size=24888KB)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeFile(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:355)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:434)
        at scave.reforge.img.DBitmap.readBitmap(DBitmap.java:327)
        at scave.reforge.img.DBitmap.updateBitmap(DBitmap.java:306)
```

This is my code:

```
/** Our bitmap object. */
protected Bitmap _bitmap;

public void updateBitmap(Context inContext)
{
    // Reset the bitmap for good measure
    if(_bitmap != null)
    {
        _bitmap.recycle();
        _bitmap = null;
    }

    // Grab the cache file provided it exists
    final File imageFile = new File(getBitmapCacheDir(inContext), getFilename());

    // If we had a cache hit, load the bitmap from the cache
    if(imageFile.exists())
        this.readBitmap(imageFile);
    // If we had a cache miss, download the bitmap from the internet and save it in our cache
    else
        this.downloadBitmap().saveBitmap(inContext);
}

private void readBitmap(File inFilePath)
{
    _bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(inFilePath.getPath());
}

private void downloadBitmap()
{
    // Our input stream
    InputStream in = null;
    try
    {
        // Open the URL stream
        in = new java.net.URL(_url).openStream();

        // Download the bitmap
        _bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        // Log if there was an error
        Log.e("TAG", "Error downloading image", e);

        _bitmap = null;
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            // Close the input stream if it is open
            if(in != null)
                in.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            // Log if there was an error
            Log.e("TAG", "Error closing stream \"in\"", e);
        }
    }
}

private void saveBitmap(Context inContext)
{
    if(_bitmap == null)
        return;

    // Open the cache directory
    File imageFile = new File(getBitmapCacheDir(inContext), getFilename());

    // Our output stream
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try
    {
        // Open the output stream
        out = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);

        // Write the bitmap to the cache
        _bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        // Log if there was an error
        Log.e("saveBitmap()", "Error while saving bitmap : ", e);
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            // Close the output stream
            if(out != null)
                out.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            // Log if there was an error
            Log.e("saveBitmap()", "Error while closing out : ", e);
        }
    }
}
```

None of the other questions I've found about this sort of error have been able to explain why the app works if I just download from the internet all the time but not if I read bitmaps from file. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Stab in the dark, but have you checked the PPI on the images? I got seemingly random memory crashes on some images on older devices. After a lot of Googling, I opened the images in a photo image editing tool and saw that I had somehow created them at 300 PPI. I fixed the images to a normal level of 72 and *poof*, errors gone.

Answer (score 1):

you have to scale down version of bitmap in android image view . you accessing very large size of image with high resolution image . so you have to scale it down version of bitmap and load it in image view. for more info Google is your friend. and please see the [android developer site](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html).

use BitmapFactory.option allows you to read the dimensions and type of the image data prior to construction

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.myimage, options);
int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
String imageType = options.outMimeType;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set an very large image resource for instance as a bitmap file for a ImageView, Android automatically scales it down for you and loads the image.

If you expand the bitmap from the file yourself (from a file say...) , you will face this error. The maximum supported size of Canvas in Android is 2048 X 2048 .

You can use the Picasso library for downloading and displaying images.
It will automatically detect the size of the ImageView and load the bitmap accordingly.

in your build file, add

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

And in your activity/fragment add

```
Picasso.with(this).load("Image Url/ Local Uri / File").into(ImageView)
```

or

```
Picasso.with(this).load("Image Url/ Local Uri / File").fit().into(ImageView)
```

You can even use Caching as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978828/using-disk-caching-in-picasso-android-lib/30686992?noredirect=1#comment49644188_30686992)

Answer (score 0):

Bitmap with large image you have to scale image with BitmapFactory.Options.inSampleSize . The sample size is the number of pixels in either dimension that correspond to a single pixel in the decoded bitmap. When you use inSampleSize = 4 it returns an image that is 1/4 the width/height of the original.You can also see the more detail in [android developer site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize).

```
 try {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        if (bitmap != null) {
            bitmap.recycle();
            bitmap = null;
        }
        bitmap = decodeFileWithSmallSize("sdcard_path");
    } 
 catch (OutOfMemoryError e)
    {
        Log.e("TAG",
                "OutOfMemoryError Exception" + e.getMessage());
    }

    //pass your sdcard path where your image is store 
    private Bitmap decodeFileWithSmallSize(String sdcard_path) {
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 4;
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(sdcard_path, options);
    return myBitmap;
}
```