# How to cache profile picture with Picasso in MaterialDrawer library

Tags: android, caching, navigation-drawer, picasso, materialdrawer

I'm using [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) library and loading profile images with [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso). But I am unable to save it locally with Picasso and loading it from cache in the future.

Before creating the drawer,

```
 //below line is for loading profile image from url
    DrawerImageLoader.init(new DrawerImageLoader.IDrawerImageLoader() {
        @Override
        public void set(ImageView imageView, Uri uri, Drawable placeholder) {
            Picasso.with(imageView.getContext()).load(uri).placeholder(placeholder).into(imageView);
        }

        @Override
        public void cancel(ImageView imageView) {
            Picasso.with(imageView.getContext()).cancelRequest(imageView);
        }

        @Override
        public Drawable placeholder(Context ctx) {
            return null;
        }

    });
```

I wrote this as material library says. Then I set my profile picture:

`String myURL = "http://www.american.edu/uploads/profiles/large/chris_palmer_profile_11.jpg"
profile = new ProfileDrawerItem().withName(person.getFullName()).withEmail(person.getStMajorName()).withIcon(myURL)`

But everytime I run the app, it loads it from the internet.

How can I cache the image?

Comment: How do you know its loading from the internet everytime?

Comment: Normally Picasso takes care about caching and everything. And the MaterialDrawer does not modify this behavior. Are your sure caching does not work? Else try Glide?

Answer (score 1):

By default `Picasso` comes with a default implementation which are suitable for most usecases.

There are various solutions which allow you to force `Picasso` to load the images from the cache. Or to change this behavior.

You should check out the following **StackOverFlow** question which come with different solutions to your issue:

[How do I use disk caching in Picasso?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978828/how-do-i-use-disk-caching-in-picasso)