# Picasso download didn't start?

Tags: android, picasso

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_view);

        Context context = this;

        Picasso.with(this)
                .load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png")
                .placeholder(R.drawable.appleadn)
                .noFade()
                .into(imgView);


    }
```

I am new in android and i use picasso for download images but above with that code give me no error placeholder is also shown but image is downloaded or started yet
where i am wrong?
Or is there flag or something setting for picasso or OkHttp is must for use picasso?

Comment: please post some more information. What do the logs say?

Comment: Have you added the Internet permission?

Comment: no i didn't add the internet permission...

Comment: Thanks @Eric it works i added the internet permission.

Comment: @Nicky, Glad i could help you out. Please accept my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Hey image is not cache in memory what should i do for save in external storage for image.

Comment: @Nicky see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978828/how-do-i-use-disk-caching-in-picasso).