# Picasso and Firebase Storage

Tags: java, android, firebase, picasso, firebase-storage

Am trying to load an Image in the ImageView using `Firebase Storage` and `Picasso`, but it shows a null pointer exception in the logcat . Where am i wrong please.Below is my `MainActiviy.class`

```
package oerrride.we.huzykamz.imageretrieval;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public FirebaseStorage mStorage;
    ImageView img;

    StorageReference storageRef = mStorage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://askdoctor-546bf.appspot.com");
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mStorage= FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

        img =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
        StorageReference spaceRef = storageRef.child("askdoctor/namasuba.jpg");
        String url = spaceRef.getBucket();


        System.out.println("Here is the print of url : "+url);
        Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(url)
                .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).
                resize(50, 50)
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(img);


    }
}
```

Then this is my logcat Error .

```
      09-24 21:05:50.767 17655-17655/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
09-24 21:05:50.799 17655-17655/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase I/art: Late-enabling JIT
09-24 21:05:50.844 17655-17655/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase I/art: JIT created with code_cache_capacity=2MB compile_threshold=1000
09-24 21:05:50.946 17655-17655/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase-1/lib/x86
09-24 21:05:51.566 17655-17669/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
09-24 21:05:51.789 17655-17662/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase W/art: Suspending all threads took: 53.648ms
09-24 21:05:51.827 17655-17669/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 9452000 but found 8087470
09-24 21:05:51.829 17655-17655/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 9452000 but found 8087470
09-24 21:05:51.830 17655-17655/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.flags:1 and remote module com.google.android.gms.flags:0
09-24 21:05:51.830 17655-17655/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase I/DynamiteModule: Selected local version of com.google.android.gms.flags
09-24 21:05:51.850 17655-17655/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.crash not found.
09-24 21:05:51.852 17655-17655/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 9452000 but found 8087470
09-24 21:05:51.852 17655-17655/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.crash:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.crash:0
09-24 21:05:51.853 17655-17655/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase E/FirebaseCrash: Failed to initialize crash reporting
                                                                                        com.google.firebase.crash.internal.zzg$zza: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsb$zza: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
                                                                                            at com.google.firebase.crash.internal.zzg.zzbq(Unknown Source)
                                                                                            at com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                                            at com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                            at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                            at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                                                                                            at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                                                                                            at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzek(Unknown Source)
                                                                                            at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                                                            at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1748)
                                                                                            at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1723)
                                                                                            at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5153)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4748)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4688)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                         Caused by: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsb$zza: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
                                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsb.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                            at com.google.firebase.crash.internal.zzg.zzbq(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                            at com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash.<init>(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                            at com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash.getInstance(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                            at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                            at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                            at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                            at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzek(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                            at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                            at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1748) 
                                                                                            at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1723) 
                                                                                            at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5153) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4748) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4688) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
09-24 21:05:51.896 17655-17655/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 9452
09-24 21:05:51.896 17655-17655/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
09-24 21:05:51.964 17655-17655/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
09-24 21:05:52.028 17655-17686/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 9452000 but found 8087470
09-24 21:05:52.142 17655-17690/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 9452000 but found 8087470
09-24 21:05:52.143 17655-17690/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.firebasestorage not found.
09-24 21:05:52.143 17655-17690/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.firebasestorage:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.firebasestorage:0
09-24 21:05:52.143 17655-17690/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase E/NetworkRqFactoryProxy: NetworkRequestFactoryProxy failed with a RemoteException:
                                                                                                com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsb$zza: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
                                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsb.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzami.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzami.zzi(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                    at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.zzcxz(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                    at com.google.firebase.storage.zzb.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
09-24 21:05:52.143 17655-17690/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase E/GetMetadataTask: Unable to create firebase storage network request.
                                                                                          android.os.RemoteException
                                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzami.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzami.zzi(Unknown Source)
                                                                                              at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.zzcxz(Unknown Source)
                                                                                              at com.google.firebase.storage.zzb.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
09-24 21:05:52.144 17655-17690/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
                                                                                           An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
                                                                                            Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0
09-24 21:05:52.144 17655-17690/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase E/StorageException: null
                                                                                           android.os.RemoteException
                                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzami.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzami.zzi(Unknown Source)
                                                                                               at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.zzcxz(Unknown Source)
                                                                                               at com.google.firebase.storage.zzb.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                                               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
09-24 21:05:52.172 17655-17666/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 11792(944KB) AllocSpace objects, 5(100KB) LOS objects, 66% free, 1226KB/3MB, paused 6.481ms total 46.096ms
09-24 21:05:52.397 17655-17698/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
09-24 21:05:52.481 17655-17655/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase W/FA: Service connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, resolution=null, message=null}
09-24 21:05:52.579 17655-17698/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
09-24 21:05:52.747 17655-17698/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
09-24 21:05:52.747 17655-17698/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xabe30560, error=EGL_SUCCESS
09-24 21:05:52.899 17655-17662/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.593ms
09-24 21:06:02.284 17655-17686/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
09-24 21:06:02.307 17655-17686/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 9452000 but found 8087470
09-24 21:06:02.310 17655-17655/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase W/FA: Service connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, resolution=null, message=null}
09-24 21:06:09.863 17655-17662/oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.043ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the following statement executes during initialization of the Activity object, `mStorage` has not yet been initialized and is null:

```
StorageReference storageRef = mStorage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://askdoctor-546bf.appspot.com");
```

Change the declaration of `storageRef` to remove the initializer:

`StorageReference storageRef;`

Then initialize it in `onCreate()`:

```
mStorage= FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
mStorageRef = mStorage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://askdoctor-546bf.appspot.com");
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, but why does the Url of Firebase not loading an image , even when i copy it in the browser it doesnt load why?@qbix

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifah: You need to use `getDownloadUrl()` instead of `getBucket()`.  See this answer for example code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37701878/4815718

Comment: Thanks @qbix, i have done that but, App loads while showing nothing , it doesn'nt crash , check my logcat , i have updated it. I see its saying Google play services are out of date , but i have just updated them. Is there something wrong in the code or.

Comment: Man , this thing seems easybut not easy , uisng `Picasso` and `FirebaseStorage` , it has totally refused.

Comment: The Google Play Services installed on your device or emulator is out of date.  You need to update it.