# I need to store image in cache memory by using url of the image ....Is there any way to do this

Tags: android, firebase, bitmap, firebase-realtime-database

I am not able to find that how to store image into cache memory by using url of the image...is there any way to do this...Please help me to do this..thanks in advance

Comment: use the glide library to cache image here is a good tutorial https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-caching-basics

Comment: Theres some good info about this here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37699688/cache-images-local-from-google-firebase-storage

Answer (score 0):

You can very simply implement a bitmap factory with you web service calls.

As an example:

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
try {
    URL url = new URL(src);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.connect();
    InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    return myBitmap;
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Log exception
    return null;
}
```

}