# Offline image persistance with firebase storage and flutter

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter

I am successfully managing to take a photo and upload it to firebase if I have an internet connection. I have also seen that you can set firebase database to persist data when offline but I can't see any documentation on if this is possible with firebase storage.

If this isn't possible what is the best way to approach this if any? Should I save images as base64 then to sharedPreferences? Or as actual files then upload them?

Thanks for any insights

Comment: There is no built-in support in Cloud Storage for Firebase to keep images on disk. Most folks end up using a library like Glide or Picasso to accomplish this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37699688/cache-images-local-from-google-firebase-storage

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I had the same problem. Persistence in Firebase Storage in flutter is not working. I don't know why, but this plugin in Dart helps to cache images from the given url for faster loading. Have a look at this [plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cached_network_image).

Comment: This should be comment as this does not answer the question.

Comment: Just had my time wasted trying to use this out dated plugin, you are linking.