# How to Display Image From cache using picasso image loader when wifi is off?

Tags: android, picasso

Display Image from url using picasso image loader,it working fine but i wont display image from cache when wifi is off state.

```
 ImageView photo=(ImageView)findViewByid(R.id.photo);
 Picasso.with(context)
                    .load("thumburl")
                    .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .error(R.mipmap.pattern1)
                    .into(photo);
```

Comment: tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978828/how-do-i-use-disk-caching-in-picasso ??

Comment: Thank you it's Working #Rahul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first add the **OkHttp** to the gradle build file of the app module :

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
```

then add this code to your class :

```
  Picasso.with(context).load("thumburl")
                        .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE) 
                        .into(photo, new Callback() {
                            @Override 
                            public void onSuccess() { 

                            } 

                            @Override 
                            public void onError() { 
                              //Try for online if no data in cached or cached failed 
                                Picasso.with(context) 
                                        .load("thumburl") 
                                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                                .error(R.drawable.user_error)
                                        .into(photo); 
                            } 
                        });
```

Comment: I assume that you already added okhttp library. Thanks for updating the answer.