# Load image with Picasso when offline using SSL

Tags: android, picasso

I actually use Picasso in my project. The problem is : it seem there is not cache so the image are reloading all the time the url (https).

I would like to have the images in the disk cache.
I want the cache of the picture when the image was already downloaded, not depending if the WIFI is off or not.

I have created a class (**PicassoTrustAll.class**) to get my images from a HTTPS url :

```
    public class PicassoTrustAll {

        private static Picasso mInstance = null;

        private PicassoTrustAll(Context context) {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            client.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String s, SSLSession sslSession) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
            TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
                @Override
                public void checkClientTrusted(
                        java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] x509Certificates,
                        String s) throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {
                }

                @Override
                public void checkServerTrusted(
                        java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] x509Certificates,
                        String s) throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {
                }

                @Override
                public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] {};
                }
            } };
            try {
                SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
                sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
                client.setSslSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mInstance = new Picasso.Builder(context)
                    .downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(client))
                    .listener(new Picasso.Listener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception) {
                            Log.e("PICASSO", String.valueOf(exception));
                        }
                    }).build();

        }

        public static Picasso getInstance(Context context) {
            if (mInstance == null) {
                new PicassoTrustAll(context);
            }
            return mInstance;
        }
}
```

And I use it like this :

```
PicassoTrustAll.getInstance(v.getContext())
                .load(image_url)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.progress_animation)
                .into(photo);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Display Image From cache using picasso image loader when wifi is off?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39137700/how-to-display-image-from-cache-using-picasso-image-loader-when-wifi-is-off)

Comment: No really because I want the cache picture when the image was already downloaded, not when the WIFI is off.

Comment: But I think that also applies to your situation.

Comment: I try it but I have the placeholder loading all the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working using OKHTTP :

```
Picasso.with(context).load("url")
                        .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE) 
                        .into(photo, new Callback() {
                            @Override 
                            public void onSuccess() { 

                            } 

                            @Override 
                            public void onError() {
                                Picasso.with(context) 
                                        .load("url") 
                                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                                .error(R.drawable.user_error)
                                        .into(picture); 
                            } 
                        });
```