# Picasso with OKHttp not displaying image: log error

Tags: android, android-studio, picasso, okhttp

I'm trying to download and cache an image with picasso from a webserver. I found a solution right here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30686992/6884064

```
   Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(this);
            builder.downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(this,Integer.MAX_VALUE));
            Picasso built = builder.build();
            built.setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
            built.setLoggingEnabled(true);
            Picasso.setSingletonInstance(built);

          Picasso.with(this)
                  .load("http://i.imgur.com/Q85lste.jpg")
                  .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
                  .into(coverImg);
```

Build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0'
```

When I run it my placeholder image disappears but the new image doesn't load in.

The run log gives me this:

```
D/Picasso: Main        created      [R0] Request{http://i.imgur.com/Q85lste.jpg}
D/Picasso: Dispatcher  enqueued     [R0]+6ms 
D/Picasso: Hunter      executing    [R0]+7ms 
W/System.err: remove failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) :  /data/user/0/com.test.example1/cache/picasso-cache/journal.tmp
D/Picasso: Dispatcher  batched      [R0]+45ms for error
D/Picasso: Dispatcher  delivered    [R0]+246ms 
D/Picasso: Main        errored      [R0]+246ms
```

Anyone know what's going on here? Thanks!

**EDIT:**

It's working with this code:

```
   OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
            okHttpClient.networkInterceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(chain.request());
                    return originalResponse.newBuilder().header("Cache-Control", "max-age=" + (60 * 60 * 24 * 365)).build();
                }
            });

            okHttpClient.setCache(new Cache(getCacheDir(), Integer.MAX_VALUE));
            OkHttpDownloader okHttpDownloader = new OkHttpDownloader(okHttpClient);
            Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(this).downloader(okHttpDownloader).build();
            picasso.load("http://i.imgur.com/test.jpg").into(coverImg);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you try in android Studio emulator, clean Cache and data of app and uninstall and then install it again.
And also don't forget required permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

maybe worked. good luck.

Comment: I only had the first permission set. Adjusted it now and tried on both (my phone and the emulator. On my phone nothing changed -> still getting the same error. On my emulator I'm getting a different error saying: D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default

Comment: You right. I copy these codes from my app and forget check them! :d

Comment: I'll try to find troubleshoot with another ways to help you.

Comment: Found a solution! Thank you though