# cache image without showing glide

Tags: android, caching, android-glide

Is it possible to cache image using **glide** without showing it in the `imageView`?. If it is then how?.

Right now I'm doing this code:

```
Glide
  .with(getApplicationContext())
  .load("imageUrl")                
  .override(windowWidth(),(int)windowWidth()*0.5))
  .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL);
```

But this is not working , when app is open **glide** load image not from cache but from url.

Comment: How do you know its not taking it from cache 
?

Comment: Use `Picasso` [Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30686992/6544105)

Answer (score 9):

Since glide 4.X:

```
//to save img
RequestManager rm = Glide.with(context);
rm.load(imgUrl).submit();

//to load img
Glide.with(context)
    .applyDefaultRequestOptions(
        new RequestOptions().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL))
    .load(imgUrl)
    .into(view);
```

Based on [this](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/2069) GitHub topic

Answer (score 6):

i've never used it, but referring the documentation: have you tried the downloadOnly?

> Glide's downloadOnly() API allows you to download the bytes of an image into the disk cache so that it will be available to be retrieved later.

https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Loading-and-Caching-on-Background-Threads#downloadonly

Comment: exactly what i search. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

To preload remote images and ensure that the image is only downloaded once:

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(yourUrl)
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
    .preload();
```