# Can data be cached in Android RecyclerView Adapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-viewholder

We cache the views in ViewHolder so that too many `findViewById()` calls could be avoided. In the same way, whether data can be cached in RecyclerView Adapter?

I heard that views are cached in ViewHolder but I am not sure whether data is cached when we use Adapter? If data caching is not provided by RecyclerView Adapter, application can still be crashed if too many calls to data sources occurs?

Comment: Views are recycled. check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works.  Data has to be got from some source either from network or locally. Your adapter is a bridge between your data and reyclerview. You can lazy load the data

Comment: @Raghunandan, Thanks for the response. I do have a question though.
Who takes the responsibility of lazyloading? Is that Adapter itself?
If yes, how it is done?

Comment: read https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView

Comment: Thanks again for the much useful link. One last question.
As of my understanding, lazy loading refers to load the data only when it is really required. So, if we have enormous data to be displayed, it makes sense to use lazy loading and display only few of them at a time. But my concern is -> I want to reduce data source calls as much as possible by caching already retrieved data (some of them)

Comment: if you want some caching then use for example `android.util.LruCache`, the docs say: *"A cache that holds strong references to a limited number of values. Each time a value is accessed, it is moved to the head of a queue. When a value is added to a full cache, the value at the end of that queue is evicted and may become eligible for garbage collection."*

Comment: @pskink 
Alright, so caching implementation would depend on kind of data, right? 
lazy loading along with a cache implementation should be the best way to go, right?

Comment: yes, if you have enormous data...

Comment: yes. you can implement your own caching mechanism or use third party libs. If your getting data from network you could also paginate the same.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly you mean my by cache if you meant in the **Sense of Image** you can Use library like Picasso and perform [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978828/how-do-i-use-disk-caching-in-picasso)  and cache Images.
 and if you Mean cache in the **sense of data** your List or Array is already Working as cache.
Only visible Views in `ListView` have Data **Rest is Imaginary** only data reside within the List or array!

Answer (score -2):

**No You can't**

In Android RecyclerView, only the number of views which will be visible are created. It is handled by the onCreateViewHolder() method.

And when the user scrolls the list, the views which go out of the visible area are reused by populating it with new data. This operation is carried out in the `onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewholder, int position)` method.

As views are recycled for new data, there is no point of caching the data in viewholders.

By the way if you look at `onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)`, you will notice that there is no position parameter. which means you will not even be able to link your list item data, because the ViewHolder is going to be used for multiple positions in the list.

Comment: **No You can't** - so you are saying that **data** cannot be cached? notice that OP did not mention anything on caching the data in viewholders

Comment: How will you know which data is to be cached in the viewholder,  when you dont know the position of the viewholder when it is created

Comment: nobody wants to cache the data in viewholder, read it again: `I heard that views are cached in ViewHolder but not sure whether data is cached when we use Adapter?`

Comment: viewholder is just like any other java class, and you can store any data you want. But I'm saying what's the point when you don't know for which position the viewholder is going to be used for when it is created.

Comment: sure i can store any data but neither *i* nor *OP* wants to do that - again: he does not want to cache any data in viewholder - he is asking if the data is automagically cached in the **adapter**

Comment: @AbdulAli
I talk about RecyclerView Adapters, nothing on ViewHolders.
ViewHolder just recycle the views and data is coming through **adapter**, but that was not my concern.

Comment: Please not that viewholder contains the reference of views. So when you set data to a view for eg setting a textview, the data is stored in the textview. So indirectly viewholder stores the data set on the view

Comment: @RahulRaj Remember viewholder is the backbone of recyclerview and its adapter.

Comment: @AbdulAli
What a viewholder does, thats not my concern, please take your time to read my question properly.

Comment: @RahulRaj Well adapter is normally initialized with the list data. So the data  is cached in the adapter.

Comment: @RahulRaj i mentioned that you dont want to cache the data in viewholders 3 times already but  AbdulAli does not seem to listen... ;-(