# How to make an image always in memory Picasso

Tags: android, picasso

I 've just started use Picasso in Android, and I have a problem with it that I realize when Picasso load too many Image make it out of memory and the previous loaded images will be remove from memory, so when i come back Picasso will load from internet again. I just want to make some important images will always in the memory, like Profile Picture.
Should I storage image in disk memory or use another library or something else.Can someone guide me the solution?

Comment: Have u check this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978828/how-do-i-use-disk-caching-in-picasso

Comment: yes, i have checked, I try it but it doesn't work

Comment: I don't know what Picasso is doing, but Glide for example is also using a disk cache for the images it loads.

Comment: Try loading the image using glide. It has two level of caching disk caching and memory cache. Image will load from memory cache if there is no value in memory cache means it will load from disk cache .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `Glide` for your requirement , **Its a powerful image loading library**

In your app gradle do this

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  google()
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
}
```

> Usage:-

```
Glide.with(context)
                .load(url_here)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(holder.imageView);
```

This is the key `DiskCacheStrategy.ALL` which caches all versions of the image