# How can I add caching function in picasso?

Tags: android, picasso, image-caching

How can I implement following task

Use an image caching framework and a networking framework?

Below My implementation

```
Picasso.get().load(introduction.getImage()).into(holder.imageView);
```

And I found this sample:

```
Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(Uri.parse(getItem(position).getStoryBigThumbUrl()))
    .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
    .into(holder.storyBigThumb, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError() {
            // Try again online if cache failed
            Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(Uri.parse(getItem(position)
                            .getStoryBigThumbUrl()))
            .placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
            .error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)
                    .into(holder.storyBigThumb);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use disk caching in Picasso?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978828/how-do-i-use-disk-caching-in-picasso)

Comment: what is  your question ? what kind of problem you faced it?

Comment: @sasikumar I have already wrote my questions

Answer (score 0):

> You can use `NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE` with `Picasso`.

```
if (introduction.getImage() != null) {
            Picasso.get().load(introduction.getImage()).resize(100, 100).centerCrop().
                    networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).into(holder.imageView, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Exception e) {
                    Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.ic_contact).resize(100, 100).centerCrop().
                            into(holder.imageView);
                }
            });

        }
```

Comment: @Tunder, how can I add  images from drawable folder on error method f

Comment: Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.drawableName).into(imageView);