# How to load images from internet in android app quickly?

Tags: android

I'm a beginner in android and i want to load some images from internet in my app. I heard about libraries such as Glide and Picasso. Can anyone please tell me which library is the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your title you use the word "quickly". Theres no such thing, unless you have a cache implementation. As you pointed out those two libraries help in retrieving images from the web and displaying them into imageView, also support cache features so that images previously displayed can load faster in the near future.

Simple example of [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/):

```
Picasso.get().load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

Want to know more about cache in Picasso? [Check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30686992/3290977)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article here](https://medium.com/@multidots/glide-vs-picasso-930eed42b81d) both are really nice to be used , but I would suggest Picasso because it just updated to 3.0 + it is lighter than Glide when it comes to : 
library size and method count .