# Stuttering effects during scroll using android Picasso or Glide

Tags: android, performance, picasso, android-glide, onscrolllistener

I tried both image frameworks [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) and [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to load images from SD and display them in **ReceyclerView's** list item's **ImageView**. The **ReceyclerView** list contains around 50 items and more.

Whenever I scroll down the list, the sroll movement is not fluent and sometimes starts stuttering which worsen the UX in my opinion. I only load images from disc (SD) inside a Fragment.

For **Picasso** I used following code:

```
Picasso.with(activity.getApplicationContext())
    .load(Constants.ABS_PATH_USER_IMAGE + user.getPicture() + ".jpg")
    .tag(PicassoOnScrollListener.TAG)
    .resize(100, 100)
    .centerCrop()
    .transform(new CircleTransform())
    .placeholder(R.drawable.default_user)
    .error(R.drawable.default_user)
    .into(holder.thumbNail);
```

The Picasso **ScrollListener** looks like:

```
public class PicassoOnScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {
public static final Object TAG = new Object();
private static final int SETTLING_DELAY = 500;

private static Picasso sPicasso = null;
private Runnable mSettlingResumeRunnable = null;

public PicassoOnScrollListener(Context context) {
    if(this.sPicasso == null) {
        this.sPicasso = Picasso.with(context.getApplicationContext());
    }
}

@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int scrollState) {
    if(scrollState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
        recyclerView.removeCallbacks(mSettlingResumeRunnable);
        sPicasso.resumeTag(TAG);

    } else if(scrollState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING) {
        mSettlingResumeRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                sPicasso.resumeTag(TAG);
            }
        };

        recyclerView.postDelayed(mSettlingResumeRunnable, SETTLING_DELAY);

    } else {
        sPicasso.pauseTag(TAG);
    }
}}
```

To add **ScrollListener** to the ReceyclerView I did following:

```
myRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new PicassoOnScrollListener(getContext()));
```

For **Glide** I simply used follwong code sample:

```
Glide
    .with(mActivity.getApplicationContext())
    .load(Constants.ABS_PATH_USER_IMAGE + author.getPicture() + ".jpg")
    .centerCrop()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.default_user)
    .crossFade()
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
    .transform(new GlideCircleTransform(mActivity.getApplicationContext()))
    .into(holder.thumbNailAuthor);
```

Have you got any ideas how to achieve a smooth scroll movement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

in imageView in layout

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this to your RecyclerView:

```
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(20);
recyclerView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
```

Besides I used .Fit() intead of .Resize() and removed .CenterCrop(). Now it works like a charm.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26856487/recyclerview-painfully-slow-to-load-cached-images-form-picasso)