# RecyclerView: buggy scroll effect (Android)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, androidx

This is my first post here on StackOverflow. I have an issue with the horizontal `androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView`: the scrolling effect is really buggy. I'm using a custom adapter, but I don't think that's the issue. I'm also using Picasso for the images.

- **RecyclerView**:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/test2"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"/>
```

- **MainFilmsListAdapter.java** (my adapter):

```
public class MainFilmsListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainFilmsListAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private List<MainFilms> filmsList;
    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView mainFilmsTitle, mainFilmsURL;
        ImageView mainFilmsImage;
        MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mainFilmsTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.main_films_item_title);
            mainFilmsURL = view.findViewById(R.id.main_films_item_url);
            mainFilmsImage = view.findViewById(R.id.main_films_item_image);
        }
    }
    public MainFilmsListAdapter(List<MainFilms> filmsList) {
        this.filmsList = filmsList;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.main_films_item, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        MainFilms film = filmsList.get(position);
        holder.mainFilmsTitle.setText(film.getMainFilmsTitle());
        holder.mainFilmsURL.setText(film.getMainFilmsURL());
        Picasso.get()
                .load(filmsList.get(position).getMainFilmsImage())
                .fit()
                .centerCrop()
                .into(holder.mainFilmsImage);

    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return filmsList.size();
    }
}
```

- **MainFilms.java**:

```
public class MainFilms {
    String mainFilmsTitle;
    String mainFilmsImage;
    String mainFilmsURL;

    public MainFilms(String mainFilmsTitle, String mainFilmsURL, String mainFilmsImage) {
        this.mainFilmsTitle = mainFilmsTitle;
        this.mainFilmsURL = mainFilmsURL;
        this.mainFilmsImage = mainFilmsImage;
    }

    public String getMainFilmsTitle() {
        return mainFilmsTitle;
    }

    public String getMainFilmsURL() {
        return mainFilmsURL;
    }

    public String getMainFilmsImage() {
        return mainFilmsImage;
    }
}
```

- **MainActivity.java** (RecyclerView):

```
mAdapter = new MainFilmsListAdapter(filmsList);
LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

- **Result:** https://i.imgur.com/64CPQDY.mp4 (I can't upload because of the file size, and sorry for the bad quality, but my PC is slow)

I can't figure out where the problem is, I've been looking for a solution for more than 5 hours. All I notice is that the view freezes when it reaches a certain item in the RecyclerView. I also tested the app on my Android cellphone. The number of itmes in the RecyclerView is constant.

Comment: I think the problem is with images loading. Try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26856487/recyclerview-painfully-slow-to-load-cached-images-form-picasso

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem. Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a problem with images loading.

You can try to read this related question and answers - [Recyclerview painfully slow to load cached images form Picasso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26856487/recyclerview-painfully-slow-to-load-cached-images-form-picasso)