# In picasso , Image background (holder) always shown when scrolling up or down

Tags: android, picasso

I am having problem in picasso , when i scroll up or down the image is loading again so the background is showing again ,this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31167376/uil-picasso-images-in-adapter-always-reload-when-stop-scrolling) describe my problem, however applying the answer of user Taha didnt work for me, and for now i cant using something else then picasso.

[image]

this is my code

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        System.out.println("entering adapter1");

        View row = convertView;
      final  ViewHolder holder;


        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mcontext);
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imageTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        final Listitem item = getItem(position);
        System.out.println("item.getUrl() ");
        System.out.println(item.getUrl());
        Picasso.with(mcontext).setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
        holder.imageTitle.setText(item.getId());
        Picasso.
                with(mcontext).
                load(item.getUrl())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.logo)
                .fit()
                .noFade()
                .into(holder.imageView)
                .memoryCache(new LruCache(cacheSize))
        ;

        holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                ArrayList<Listitem> personArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                personArrayList.add(new Listitem(item.getId(), item.getUrl()));

                Intent intent = new Intent(mcontext,SingleViewActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Person_List", personArrayList);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                mcontext.startActivity(intent);

                Log.d("OnImageButton", "Clicked");
            }
        });


        return row;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView imageTitle;
        ImageView imageView;
    }
```

edit errors

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
int cacheSize = 4 * 1024 * 1024; // 4MiB    
Picasso myNewPicasso = new Picasso.Builder(context).memoryCache(new LruCache(cacheSize)).build();  

    myNewPicasso.with(mcontext)
                .load(item.getUrl())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.logo)
                .fit()
                .noFade()
                .into(holder.imageView);
```

Comment: Yes, and uste this instead the "main" Picasso.

Comment: what do you mean to put it as main picasso?i am new to picasso, I also had maxsize cannot resolve as type

Comment: Okay ill try it .. side question will that effect the memory if have alot of images displayed in listview?

Comment: I tried your code and the background is still shoing hen I am scrolling also, the application is being hanged

Comment: Try to increment the cache size.

Comment: I am thinking to insert the images into sqllite table then read the image from there .. would you think it would improve memory and performance